# LINQ Question - Query

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a table which stores cultural variants for a particular key for example.

```
RecordID   Key    CultureID   Description
1          1      en-GB       Hour
2          1      es-ES       hora
3          2      en-GB       Swimming
```

I have this as an IEnumerable Given the paremeter of @CultureID="es-ES" I want to return the following. In short If the cultural variant exists then return it for the given parameter, else return the "en-GB" entry ( Which Allways Exists ). Can someone help me with the LINQ query for this.

```
RecordID   Key    CultureID   Description
2          1      es-ES       hora
3          2      en-GB       Swimming
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming this is LINQ-to-SQL, not LINQ to objects?  Or by table do you mean an in-memory data structure?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that booleans sort as [false, true], so the following query will sort all matches *not* equal to `en-GB` first, and then `en-GB`.

```
var result = (from x in variants
              where x.CultureID == cultureID || x.CultureID == "en-GB"
              orderby x.CultureID == "en-GB"
              select x).First();
```

This query will give an error if not even any "en-GB" entry exists for a given key (`First` demands at least one record), but as you stated, it always exists. If you're not so sure it does, use `FirstOrDefault`.

Note that many LINQ providers support this idiom, it is not just usable for IEnumerable/Lists. So you can even combine the filter on key and culture as part of the LINQ query, so you could let the database sort it out for you, and you don't get the entire list of translations back, just the one you want:

```
var result = (from x in db.Translations
              where x.Key == someKey
                && (x.CultureID == cultureID || x.CultureID == "en-GB")
              orderby x.CultureID == "en-GB"
              select x).First();
```

Comment: How does that convert to SQL?   Just interested.

Comment: I've tested it for Entity Framework and Linq-to-SQL, and both frameworks support this kind of query. It basically translates to `CASE WHEN x.CultureID = 'en-GB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`. So be careful if you want to do this for large intermediate sets. Here you know you will only match a few records with your WHERE, but if you'd try to partition your sort order this way, you might not hit the proper indexes. I don't know of a general solution to this, cause UNIONs might not be very performant either. A pre-computed column (e.g. IsCatchAllTranslation BIT) could probably be useful.

Comment: I just did the same test and it creates a bit to sort by.  Either way thats neat.  Thanks>!

Answer (score 1):

There is always another way.

**Union:**

```
IEnumerable<Varriant> result = variants
    .Where(x=>x.CultureID   == CultureID)
    .Union(variants.Where(x=> x.CultureID   == "en-GB"))
.ToList();

Variant v = variants.FirstOrDefault();
```

**Other**

```
IEnumerable<Varriant> result = (
     from x in variants
      where x.CultureID   == CultureID || x.CultureID   == "en-GB"
     select x


).ToList();

Varriant r = null;
if(result.Length <= 1){
   r = result.FirstOrDefault();

}else{
     r = result.First(x=>x.CultureID   !="en-GB");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to make two queries. One to try to get the value for the cultural variant (using SingleOrDefault()), then check if the returned value is null. If it is, do the same query with en-BG instead of the one given as parameter.

```
var result = (from i in records where RecordID = 1 && CultureID = "es-ES" select i).SingleOrDefault();

if (result == null) result = = (from i in records where RecordID = 1 && CultureID = "es-ES" select i).Single();
```

Or maybe using some orderby clause?